# How to find across all open worksheets in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

CTRL+F opens the find in one sql worksheet in Oracle Sql Developer tool. But I want to find across all open worksheets. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible today, but in our new platform that we're developing, this will be a feature.

Current offering of Oracle SQL Developer will go into maintenance mode, and our new product platform will be offered as 'SQL Developer Next.'

More information to follow this year.

*Disclaimer: I'm an employee of Oracle and am a product manager for SQL Developer.*

Answer (score -1):

You can click on the "Search" menu in the main menu bar, then select "Find in All Worksheets" in oracle sql dev.

Comment: If you are mentioning the binocular icon on the bar, it is find database object. And there is no "Find in all worksheets" option. Otherwise please mention the menu location or upload a picture please.